# How to select first in such sql code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have such sql:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * 
            FROM car 
            LEFT JOIN client 
                ON car.CodeClient = client.Code
            LEFT JOIN telephone 
                ON car.CodeClient = telephone.CodeClient 
            WHERE Marka Like '$Marka' 
                and Model Like '%$Model%' 
                and EngineVol Like '%$EngineVol%' 
                and EngineType Like '%$EngineType%' 
                and DateMade Like '%$DateMade%'
                               ");
```

And I need to select CodeClient and TelephoneNumber from telephone table, but select first entry for every Client, not all telephone, but first. Grouping is not the solving!

Comment: `client.Code` is uniq ? and did you try grouping by `client.Code`

Comment: is uniq, but grouping groupes code client and i need for more entries!

Comment: Please define "first entry": "First" as "oldest"? Or like "anything the DB spits out first but only one"?

Comment: first, first is entered in db

Comment: your question is still a little ambiguous.  What is the primary key?  Do you have a field that can help indicate the oldest, like a timestamp?  Can you explain in words what you are trying to get, like " a list of the first entry for a client and car info and phone number?  It's hard to tell which tables the fields are from, and what exactly you are looking for

Comment: CodeClient in all this is primary. Don't think about datestamp now, get me simple answer. ill get in with help, that telephone has key telid wich is uniq and ai, so i get first with help of this key (key with smaller value),

Comment: SELECT * FROM car c, (SELECT * FROM telephone ORDER BY CodeT) t, (SELECT * FROM client) cl                                                                                                                  
                                                            WHERE ((c.CodeClient = t.CodeClient) and (c.CodeClient = cl.Code) and Marka Like '$Marka' and Model Like '%$Model%' and EngineVol Like '%$EngineVol%' and EngineType Like '%$EngineType%' and DateMade Like '%$DateMade%')
                                                            GROUP BY Model, Marka, EngineType, DateMade

Answer (score -1, accepted):

wouldn't this work? Sorry if it's not what you're looking for, but the question is a little unclear:

```
ORDER BY car.id LIMIT 1
```

or just:

```
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: i dont understand were to write this, it dont work as i do yet

Comment: Try to put it in in the end of the query: and DateMade Like '%$DateMade%' LIMIT 1");